# JBPM 4.4 EXCEPTIONAL HANDLING

Tags: jbpm

I am not getting link or material on how to handle exceptions in JBPM 4.4
 Any body have any pointers or link , please do update me.

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 1):

you can handle exception at node level like this

```
<node name="Update Ops DC Review">
    <action class="com.vis.vt.client.dc.process.handler.OperationsReviewActionHandler" name="discontinuanceActionHandler"></action>
    <exception-handler exception-class="java.lang.Exception">
        <action name="exceptionHandler" class="com.vis.vt.client.dc.node.ExceptionHandler"></action>
    </exception-handler>
    <transition to="Approve Client DC" name="Accept"></transition>
    <transition to="Complete" name="Deny"></transition>
</node>
```

and here is code for exception handler class as mentioned in above XML;

```
public class ExceptionHandler extends NodeHandler implements ActionHandler {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1322446214823660013L;

    public void execute(ExecutionContext context) throws Exception {

        HelpDeskTaskData helpDeskTaskData = new HelpDeskTaskData();

        ProcessInstance pi = context.getProcessInstance();

        Node node = context.getToken().getNode();

        String errorNodeName = node.getName();

        long processInstanceId = pi.getId();
        Throwable cause = context.getException();

        Date currentDate = new Date();
        String processName = pi.getProcessDefinition().getName();

        helpDeskTaskData.setErrorNodeName(errorNodeName);
        helpDeskTaskData.setProcessInstanceId(processInstanceId);
        helpDeskTaskData.setCause(cause);
        helpDeskTaskData.setCurrentDate(currentDate);
        helpDeskTaskData.setSourceProcessName(processName);

        ITaskData taskData = (ITaskData) context.getVariable("taskData");
        helpDeskTaskData.setComposedTaskData(taskData);

        pi.suspend();

        ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngine.getInstance();
        processEngine.publish(helpDeskTaskData);

    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Related to the JBPM Version (7.x) You can check out the [official JBPM User documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.42.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#jBPMExceptionManagement).
But a much nicer summary of the possible options can be found [here](https://karinavarela.me/2020/06/01/dealing-with-unexpected-errors-in-processes/).